# How to provide method body for extern method with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I'm using the MS C# compiler to compile methods like this:

```
[Placeholder] public extern void Method();
```

The compiled method has `RVA = 0` (Relative Virtual Address).

Then, with Mono.Cecil 0.9.3, I want to fill up a method body for it.

I do it like this:

```
methodDefinition.Body = new MethodBody(methodDefinition);
// emit code...
```

When trying to save the assembly, though, I get an error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.IsInSection(Int32 rva)
    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.MoveTo(Int32 rva)
    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.PatchRawMethodBody(MethodDefinition method, CodeWriter writer, MethodSymbols& symbols)
    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteUnresolvedMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You should start by updating to Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.

Comment: @Jb Evain: OK, I will do that.

Comment: @Jb Evain: It worked! Shame on me! Thanks for the great library. Take a look at [NRoles](http://code.google.com/p/nroles/) to see how I used it.

Comment: no problem, glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ashamed to say that the solution was to just upgrade Mono.Cecil to version 0.9.5.